# TreeViewitem can't select = null

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, selection

I have a problem with the selection of a `TreeViewItem` in my tree view. My following code returns `null` when I select an item in my tree view.

What do I do wrong?

```
TreeViewItem item = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;
```

[image: You can see in this picture that when I debug it tells me the Item is null]

[image: Here you can see what the e.originalSource holds]

Comment: `e.OriginalSource` isn't a `TreeViewItem`. When you debug check the type of `e.OriginalSource`. That will likely help to solve this issue.

Comment: What is in the OriginalSource before you try to cast it to TreeViewItem?

Comment: @QualityCatalyst
the e.OriginalSource is object of RouteEventArgs as far as I see it. But when I hover over it it says TreeView. Its an Treeview Object that contains some stuff. I will update the op with another picture.

Answer (score 1):

As per your latest image, `e.OriginalSource` is a `TreeView`. When you cast `e.OriginalSource` like this:

```
TreeViewItem item = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;
```

... `item` will always be `null`. This is because your type cast cannot convert `e.OriginalSource` into your desired type. If you this hard cast instead:

```
TreeViewItem item = (TreeViewItem)e.OriginalSource;
```

You would get a `CastException` that explains you why.

So what you got to do is to cast into the correct type like this:

```
TreeViewItem tree = e.OriginalSource as TreeView; // I am a tree view :-)
```

... and then select from `tree.Items` the item you require.

Comment: Thanks this works for me. Wasnt really what I thought I could do, but works for now.

Answer (score 0):

`e.Source` and `e.OriginalSource` refer to the `TreeView` not the `TreeViewItem` selected.

Try this to get the selected item:

```
TreeViewItem item = e.NewValue as TreeViewItem;
```

Or this to get the previously selected item:

```
TreeViewItem item = e.OldValue as TreeViewItem;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but its still null for me with that approach.

Comment: @Abhay not really. It will generate exception.

Comment: @p__d..what kind of exception? NewValue is to get the value of the property after the change